# What should I use "tell" or "say"?

Tags: word-choice

Which is grammatically correct

> What can you tell about something?

or

> What can you say about something?

Comment: They’re both correct.

Answer (score 1):

The following is what Google displays when I search for "tell definition":

```
tell
    1. communicate information, facts, or news to someone in spoken or written words.
        "I told her you were coming"
    2. decide or determine correctly or with certainty.
        "you can tell they're in love"
```

Definition 1 is a synonym for "say"; however, it requires an object. If definition 1 is being used then the first sentence is not grammatical. Definition 2 does not require an object, and with this definition the first sentence is grammatical, but it does not have the same meaning as the second sentence.

In any case, the second sentence is grammatical.